# Swift Sound Effects // Why Won't My Code Work?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to make a game to teach myself swift, and cant seem to get this code to work. I am extremely new to this, and can't seem to find out why it won't work... XCode doesn't flag any problems, build sucseed, and debugger even prints "Got to Stage 1 & Got to Stage 2... anything help?

I Imported AVFoundation..

```
class GAME {

    class func SuperStartGame(playerwhowon1: SKSpriteNode) {

            var player = AVAudioPlayer()

        func PlaySound() {
            guard let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PowerUp", withExtension: "mp3")
                else {
                    print("Didn't Find URL")
                    return
            }

            do {
                print("Got to Stage 1")

                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL, fileTypeHint: "mp3")
                player.prepareToPlay()
                player.play()

                print("Got to Stage 2")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        RoundNumber += 1
        Round.text = "Round \(RoundNumber)"

        if playerwhowon1 == Mine {
            MyScore.run(addscoreM) {
                PlaySound()
                    Round.run(NewRoundForRound) {

...
```

Code keeps going.. thats the only part that is relevant to the sound. I added the sound file to Xcode, and made sure it was added tot he project target... it is in my main bundle.

Comment: Please conform to the naming convention that methods / functions and variable names start with a lowercase letter. `URL` is a struct in Swift 3. And   the code structure looks very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that your device isn't muted
2. mp3 file is copied to bundle
   [image]
3. Example VC playing sound:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {   
       var game = Game()

       @IBAction func playAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
           game.playSound()
       }

   }

   class Game {

       var player: AVAudioPlayer?

       func playSound() {
           guard let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SampleAudio", withExtension: "mp3") else {
               print("Didn't Find URL")
               return
           }

           do {
               try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
               try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

               player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL, fileTypeHint: "mp3")
               player?.prepareToPlay()
               player?.play()

           } catch let error as NSError {
               print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
           }

       }

   }
   ```